# phpWord file growth issue when adding images

Tags: php, phpword

Ok, here's the scenario.  I need to generate about 200 MS Word documents based off of data collected and stored in my database.  Generating the word docs with or without photos is a user option.  After Word doc generation I then want to create a zip file of all the files generated.  The zip part is done, the word file generation for the most part is done.

When the user chooses to generate the reports without the photos, the site queries the database and returns about 200 records for the report, and then with a foreach loop I run the PHPWord coding to generate and write the files to a temp folder and then after the foreach loop I'm running code to zip them all up and then delete the temp files.  Works great.  BUT, when the option to generate the reports WITH photos is selected, it starts generating the Word docs, but the file sizes increase every time a file is created.  First file is 70k, the second file is 140k, the third is 210k and so on, where each file should only be 70k each.  The only difference in the two operations in the inclusion of the addImage commands with the table cells like so:

```
$table->addCell()->addImage('photos/thumb_image.jpg, $imageStyle);
```

Help please!

Comment: Posting more code would be helpful

Comment: I probably should add to this a bit.  If I modify the initial query that the foreach loop is based on to output only one record at a time and leave the other code exactly the same, the site generates the Word files perfectly.  AND, if I compare the files that are supposed to be the same (normal vs inflated file size), they're identical. Same text, same images, same amount of pages, etc.

I could post a boatload of code, but I've narrowed the problem to the addImage function of PHPWord.

Comment: @Bill_VA : Which version of PhpWord do you use ? It seems that the first file has one image, and the second file stores two images, and so on... Could you give us two files ?

Comment: @Bill_VA : Could you give us more code with your loop, for example ? That will help us for helping you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Media::resetElements()` between loops that were available since 0.10.0.